# Excel Vba Problems deleting rows from mysql database

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to delete all the rows in mysql database, using vba in excel.
I have tried a lot of codes now and the closest I get, is the following code but I still get an syntax error in :

```
rsmysql.Open rsstr, coninc
```

Can someone help me correct the code, so I can get it to work please.

```
Dim rsmysql As ADODB.Recordset 'Holds records
Dim rsstr As String
Dim coninc As String
Set cnmysql = New ADODB.Connection
Set rsmysql = New ADODB.Recordset


coninc = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};Server=" & _
          Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
          ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

rsstr = "delete * from TLHMember_List;"
cnmysql.Open coninc
rsmysql.Open rsstr, coninc
MsgBox "Data has been deleted"


   Exit Sub
```

Comment: `cnmysql.Execute rsstr ` - you don't need a recordset for this.

Comment: Hi Tim
Thank you for helping can you try to post it as a full code because I tried as you stated still get the same error. I need to open the connection first so I pass the `cnmysql.Open coninc`
after that I then use the `cnmysql.Execute rsstr` instead `rsmysql.Open rsstr, coninc` of but this still give me an syntax error.

If I don't open first with the `cnmysql.Open coninc` I get an error saying I need to open the connection first

Comment: `cnmysql.Execute "delete from TLHMember_List"`  Jusr `delete from` not `delete * from`

Comment: that worked like a charm :) can you post it as an answer. And thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rsstr = "delete from TLHMember_List"
cnmysql.Open coninc
cnmysql.Execute rsstr 
MsgBox "Data has been deleted"
```